# Move images with respect to their names

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I have 10 images (123.vid1.png, 123.vid5.png, 123.vid8.png, 146.vid1.png, 146.vid5.png, 146.vid6.png, 191.vid2.png, 191.vid2.png, 191.vid5.png, 191.vid10.png) in a folder. I want to move the images with their names (123, 146, 191) to their respective folder.
Folder 123 contains (123.vid1.png, 123.vid5.png, 123.vid8.png)
Folder 146 contains (146.vid1.png, 146.vid5.png, 146.vid6.png)
Folder 191 contains (191.vid2.png, 191.vid2.png, 191.vid5.png, 191.vid10.png)

```
import os

path = "/home/samples/"
files = os.listdir(path)

def Convert(string):
    li = list(string.split(" "))
    return li

def unique(list1):
    list_set = set(list1)
    unique_list = (list(list_set))
    for x in unique_list:
        print (x)

for file in files:
    root, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
    name = root.split(".")[0]
    listing = Convert(name)
    print(listing)
```

Comment: what's the question here?

Comment: I have done till this. Now what is the next?

Answer (score 0):

```
def move_images_to_folders(list_of_images):
    for image in list_of_images:
        if image.split('.')[0] == '123':
            shutil.move(image, '123')
        elif image.split('.')[0] == '146':
            shutil.move(image, '146')
        elif image.split('.')[0] == '191':
            shutil.move(image, '191')
            
def main():
    list_of_images = os.listdir()
    move_images_to_folders(list_of_images)
```

```
def move_images_to_folders(dir_path):
    import os
    import shutil
    import glob

    images = glob.glob(dir_path + '/*.png')
    folders = list(set([image.split('.')[0] for image in images]))
    for folder in folders:
        if not os.path.exists(dir_path + '/' + folder):
            os.makedirs(dir_path + '/' + folder)
    for image in images:
        shutil.move(image, dir_path + '/' + image.split('.')[0] + '/' + image)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    dir_path = sys.argv[1]
    move_images_to_folders(dir_path)
    print('Done!')
```

Haven't tested e2e. But this should do.

Comment: Actually there are lot of images. Not only 123,146,191 but also so many. I just give an example.

Comment: Updated to work across multiple files.